# File is not uploading on Ftp server in java?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, ftp-client

Hello Every one i am working one project where i need to upload file on my ftp server with my java standalone application

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class Ftpdemo {  


     public static void main(String args[]) {  

      // get an ftpClient object  
      FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();  
      ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(300);
      FileInputStream inputStream = null;  

      try {  
       // pass directory path on server to connect  
       ftpClient.connect("ftp.mydomain.in");  

       // pass username and password, returned true if authentication is  
       // successful  
       boolean login = ftpClient.login("myusername", "mypassword");  

       if (login) {  
        System.out.println("Connection established...");  
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/simmant/Desktop/mypic.png");  

        boolean uploaded = ftpClient.storeFile("user_screens/test3.png",inputStream);



              if (uploaded) {  
         System.out.println("File uploaded successfully !");  
        } else {  
         System.out.println("Error in uploading file !");  
        }  

        // logout the user, returned true if logout successfully  
        boolean logout = ftpClient.logout();  
        if (logout) {  
         System.out.println("Connection close...");  
        }  
       } else {  
        System.out.println("Connection fail...");  
       }  

      } catch (SocketException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
      } catch (IOException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
      } finally {  
       try {  
        ftpClient.disconnect();  
       } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
       }  
      }  
     }


    }
```

its working fine for the data which is 1 or 2 kb but when i try to upload the file which is of 50 kb and 100 kb then it not working fine. The image uploaded on the server is blank .

Comment: 'its working fine for the data' ,here you refer what type of the data?

Comment: can you please tell me how much of kb of data you tried ..

Comment: i was asking what type of 'data' you have tried,please read my comment carefully?

Comment: i am working with the images..

Comment: you said in your question that 'its working fine for data which ...', so asked you that , for what kind of data it is working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with the code. As you're saying 1 or 2 kb of data uploading works fine. So, In my opinion, there is problem with your internet. Might be it's too slow to upload a file size of 50 kb or more.

Answer (score 1):

There is noting wrong with your code only issue with the file or internet speed.Code is working fine here and Also there is recommended that **NOT TO USE FTP DETAILS DIRECTLY** please avoid this stuff from application you have better option to use web service for your server related stuff.
Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

It seems you had not made connection Instances properly. 
Please refer my working code:

```
public class FTPUploader {
    FTPClient ftp = null;
    public FTPUploader() throws Exception {
        ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("c:\\ftp.log"))));
        int reply;
        ftp.connect(Constant.FTP_HOST);
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new Exception(Constant.FTP_SERVER_EXCEPTION);
        }
        ftp.login(CommonConstant.FTP_USERNAME, Constant.FTP_PASSWORD);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.TELNET_TEXT_FORMAT);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    }
    public boolean uploadFile(File localFileFullName, String fileName) throws Exception {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(localFileFullName);
        boolean reply = this.ftp.storeFile("'" + fileName +"'", input);
        disconnect();
        return reply;
    }
    public void disconnect() {
        if (this.ftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
                this.ftp.logout();
                this.ftp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(this.getClass()+ e);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start");
        FTPUploader ftpUploader = new FTPUploader();
        System.out.println(ftpUploader.uploadFile(new File("C:\\test.txt"), "Destinate_DIR"));
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

All the best ...!!!

Comment: Thanks Bhoopen, I had solution for my issue. But your code also looks interesting.